# How to get the same output format of aggregate pipeline after Insert document in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am saving document to database using `create()` method in Mongoose but I have a problem with the output result after create. I want to get the same output format of the aggregate pipeline after `create` by reusing it format instead of reprocess it manually again.

My code for insert document:

```
let result = await ProductModel.create(body);
result = await result.populate('user', 'username fullname avatar email'); 
result = await result.populate('images', 'filename mimetype url');

// send the result to client after create success
return {
    id: result._id,
    content: result.content,
    images: result.images,
    user: result.user,
    created_at: result.createdAt,
};
```

My code for find document by using aggregate pipeline:

```
...other code pipeline
{
    $project: {
        _id: 0,
        id: '$_id',
        content: 1,
        images: 1,
        user: 1,          
        created_at: 1,
    },
},
```

Both results of create and find (use aggregate pipeline) always return the same output format but I have to rehandle it by 2 different ways, I want to apply the aggregate pipeline output format for result of create. How can I resolve it problem ?

Comment: Hi everyone, who can help me?